# Bejeweled bit board applying gravity

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

I am attempting to make a Bejeweled cascade simulator with bit boards. So far, I have been able to detect and remove the matches, but now I need to have the jewels fall down. My state is represented by a list of bit boards, one for each type of jewel. I have a mask of all the jewels that are removed.

Is it possible to use some bitwise magic to do this?

Example of two initial bit boards (let's just assume that there are only two types of jewels and that it's a 4x4 board instead of 8x8). The first bit is the bottom left, the fourth bit is top left, and the last bit is top right.

```
0 0 1 1    1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0    0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1    0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0    1 1 0 1
```

After removing matches:

```
0 0 1 1    1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0    0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0    1 1 0 1
```

The mask used is:

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
```

And after gravity it should look like:

```
0 0 0 0    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0    1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1    0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0    1 1 0 1
```

This is implemented with integers, and the steps would look like:

```
[43814, 21721]       # Initial state
[35076, 4249], 26210 # State after matches have been removed, mask used to remove matches
[8962, 4149]         # State after gravity has been applied
```

Comment: Could you add a minimum example of how those bit boards look?

Comment: @tobias_k Is it understandable?

Comment: Yes, that's better. Well, you'd have to check whether a cell is `0` on all the boards, then you could drop the cell above. This would be much easier if you were using one board for all the jewels, e.g. `1` for blue, `2` for green, etc. Any particular reason you are using multiple bit boards? Even then, you could easily derive those bit boards from that one combined board.

Comment: @tobias_k The reason I'm using multiple bit boards is because there a different types of jewels. *Bit* boards are made of *bits*, which can only have two values, not eight. Also, I know where the zeroes are, and I have put that into the question.

Comment: Sorry if I keep coming back to this, but why are you using this representation? Surely space restrictions can not be a problem. Wouldn't it be much easier to represent those boards as lists of lists of integers, like `[[2,2,1,1], [0,0,0,2], [1,2,2,1], [2,2,1,2]]`? Using single integers, you'd have to shift individual bits while leaving all the other bits in place.

Comment: @tobias_k I have already done this problem with 2d lists. Now I'm trying to do it with bit boards, to reduce space as much as possible and also hopefully evaluation time. I was wondering if there was some bit magic I could do to apply gravity to an 8x8 board (64 bit integer). Would you like me to put the word 'optimisation' into the title?

Comment: What bitwise operations have you tried "to have the jewels fall down" ?

Answer (score 0):

To fall the bits you need to move your mask one row up with bitshift. Select bits from row above using the mask and copy that selected bits one row down using bit shift and oring. Simple algorithm would loop mask up to top and doing row by row movement down. But optimization could be extending the mask with bit shifts and oring with self and then moving all above bits down with single operation.

Good source for bit board operatinos is chess wiki: https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/General+Setwise+Operations

Comment: Try to figure out why it worked in original case to make it work in the more complex case too. It still only about moving bits around with shifts.

Comment: To shift different bits different amounts with single instruction one has to use multiplication. But there may not exist any single multiplication operation managing the required movement. Or it can be very hard to calculate. That why better option might be to generate separate masks for each column that has different number of elements to remove. With those masks you can then run the shifting part only once for all columns that have same number of steps to fall. To generate the fall mask with column major bit presentation (0-7bits -> 1st col) you can use integer subtraction: 0x100-0x008=0x0f8

Comment: Or I can even have a 256-entry lookup table and use that to transform each column of the bit board. To do this though, I need to come up with some number that when multiplied with the data, shifts the bits appropriately? How would I calculate this number?

Comment: I asked another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564262/one-function-with-different-arguments-to-push-certain-bits-of-an-input-integer-t) that goes into more detail about what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the left jewel board, `A`; the right, `B`; and the physical representation of the board, `AB`.
After the removals, we have:

```
               0 0 1 1      1 1 0 0     1111
AB =  A | B =  1 0 0 0  or  0 0 0 0  =  1000
               0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0     0000
               0 0 1 0      1 1 0 1     1111
```

Algorithm:

```
For each row (r, a temporary variable) above the lowest row with removals:
  For each jewel type:
    starting with the lowest row where removals occurred (AB_row)
    While r is not zero
      make a temporary copy of AB_row (AB_row_copy)
      new row for jewel_type := (row | AB_row) ^ same_row_for_other_jewel_types
      r := r & AB_row_copy
      ascend to next row of AB
```

Example:

Update the first row above the lowest row with removals:

```
# AB_row is the lowest row with removals from the bitboard that combines all
# jewel types; r_A is a copy from the A bitboard of the first row above AB_row 
r_A = 1 0 0 0, AB_row = 0 0 0 0 

  # make a copy of AB_row
  AB_row_copy = 0 0 0 0

  # calculate the new row for jewel type A
  # new row for jewel_type := (row | AB_row) ^ same_row_for_other_jewel_types
  new row for A = (1 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 0) ^ 0 0 0 0 = 1 0 0 0

  # update the fallen bits from r_A
  # r := r & AB_row_copy
  r_A = 1 0 0 0 & 0 0 0 0 = 0 0 0 0

# r_B at this row is zero, nothing to do.
r_B = 0 0 0 0
```

Update the second row above the lowest row with removals:

```
# row for A has the same process same as above
r_A = 0 0 1 1, AB_row = 1 0 0 0 // AB_row is the lowest row with removals
  AB_row_copy = 1 0 0 0
  new row for A = (0 0 1 1 | 1 0 0 0) ^ 0 0 0 0 = 1 0 1 1
  r_A = 0 0 1 1 & 1 0 0 0 = 0 0 0 0


# AB_row is the lowest row with removals from the bitboard that combines all
# jewel types; r_B is a copy from the B bitboard of the second row above AB_row
r_B = 1 1 0 0, AB_row = 1 0 1 1

  # make a copy of AB_row
  AB_row_copy = 1 0 1 1

  # calculate the new row for jewel type B
  # new row for jewel_type := (row | AB_row) ^ same_row_for_other_jewel_types
  new row for B = (1 1 0 0 | 1 0 1 1) ^ 1 0 1 1 = 0 1 0 0

  # update the fallen bits from r_B
  # r := r & AB_row_copy
  r_B = 1 1 0 0 & 1 0 1 1 = 1 0 0 0

# since there are still set bits remaining in r_B after removing the fallen 
# bit, we continue with r_B, proceeding to the next row up.

# AB_row now is the next row up from the lowest row with removals, again from
# the bitboard combining all jewel types; r_B is the same variable, now with 
# one set bit less (one "fallen" bit)
r_B = 1 0 0 0, AB_row = 0 0 0 0

  # make a copy of AB_row
  AB_row_copy = 0 0 0 0

  # calculate the new row for jewel type B
  # new row for jewel_type := (row | AB_row) ^ same_row_for_other_jewel_types
  new row for B = (1 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 0) ^ 0 0 0 0 = 1 0 0 0

  # update the fallen bits from r_B
  r_B = 1 0 0 0 & 0 0 0 0 = 0 0 0 0

  #r_B is now zero so the while loop is terminated
```

Comment: This is very unclear. Can you please state what your looping through, and define what each variable is (e.g. what is `other_jewel_types`?). If you could show me in Python, I think I would understand how it works a little better.

Comment: @Scorpion_God By `other_jewel_types`, I meant bitboards for the jewel types other than the one you are testing for. In the example loop, I started with the left-hand board `A`. `r_A` is a row from that board, used as a temporary variable that gets modified. It is `or`ed with `AB` (the total board) then `xor`ed with the right-side jewel-type board, `B`, to filter out the bits that do not belong in `A`. Can you see how the example is the same as yours? The `AB_row` with the removals gets modified as the loop progresses.

Comment: In your example, you're not `or`ing it with the whole board though. Just a row from it.

Comment: @Scorpion_God You are correct - I added "_row" to clarify. I was trying to illustrate what needs to change. There may be different ways to achieve it depending on how you choose to mask.

Comment: Okay, I still don't understand your algorithm. Let `A` ben any of the bit boards (you don't need to loop through each bit board). Let `M` be the removal mask. Let `A[0]` be the bottom row of `A`. Let `for i in range(8):` have the same meaning as in Python. Let `A[2] = 1001` mean set the third from the bottom of `A` to `1001`. Only use names that have been *defined*. If you can rewrite your algorithm like that, I would understand.

Comment: @Scorpion_God I added comments to the example in my answer - does it help make more sense to you? Although I am showing how one could update one row at a time, a practical implementation could use integers that at times include the lower rows as well.