# One function with different arguments to push certain bits of an input integer to the left

Tags: python, optimization, bit-manipulation, lookup-tables

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524678/bejeweled-bit-board-applying-gravity).

Let `x` be an 8 bit integer. I will number bits from left to right because that's how we read. If I want to get the third and fifth bits and put them in the first and second bits, with everything else as zero, I can have `f(x) = (5*x) & 0b11000000`. More concisely:

```
00a0b000 -> ab000000 | f_0b00101000(x) = (5*x) & 0b11000000
```

However if I want the fifth, sixth and eighth bits to be in the first three bits, `f(x)` is different:

```
000ab0cd -> abcd0000 | f_0b00011011(x) = ((x << 3) & 0b11000000) | (x << 4)
```

Note that the `n` in `f_n(x)` indicates which bits I care about. `n` could have any 8 bit value. Is there some common function of `x` (and a few arguments) that will push all the required bits to the left? Also, this is supposed to be fast so I would prefer to only use bitwise operations.

---

Let's say instead I'm dealing with 3 bit integers.

```
000 -> 000 | f_0(x) = (1*x) & 0
00a -> a00 | f_1(x) = (4*x) & 4
0a0 -> a00 | f_2(x) = (2*x) & 4
0ab -> ab0 | f_3(x) = (2*x) & 6
a00 -> a00 | f_4(x) = (1*x) & 4
a0b -> ab0 | f_5(x) = (3*x) & 6
ab0 -> ab0 | f_6(x) = (1*x) & 6
abc -> abc | f_7(x) = (1*x) & 7
```

These functions can all be combined into `f(x, m, a) = (m*x) & a`, and I could create a lookup table which I could index to get the values of `m` and `a` from `n`:

```
t = [(1, 0), (4, 4), (2, 4), (2, 6), (1, 4), (3, 6), (1, 6), (1, 7)]
```

So `f_n(x)` becomes `f(x, *t[n])`. I think `f(x, m, a) = (m*x) & a` is optimal for 3 bits. The naive version for 3 bits is:

```
f(x, a, b, c, d, e, f) = ((x & a) << b) |
                         ((x & c) << d) |
                         ((x & e) << f)
```

The operation count is 8 for the naive function, and 2 for the optimal (?) one. Now the naive function for 8 bits is:

```
f(x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p) = ((x & a) << b) |
                                                       ((x & c) << d) |
                                                       ((x & e) << f) |
                                                       ((x & g) << h) |
                                                       ((x & i) << j) |
                                                       ((x & k) << l) |
                                                       ((x & m) << n) |
                                                       ((x & o) << p)
```

There are 25 operations in this instruction. Is it possible to get that down to around 7 or 8, or even lower?

Comment: It is _definitively_ unclear what you're asking here. Could you edit to simplify somehow? And I think the title does not really match your description?

Comment: BTW, I doesn't help to anything to complain in a comment about "blind down-votes". The downvoter is gone long ago and will not see your comment. Other peoples will.

Comment: Typiaclly, bits are counted from the other end. Or am I stuck in Gulliver's travels world?

Comment: Is this some kind of "left shift with a mask" ? With arguments in that order `masked_shift_left(mask, shift)` ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux You can `or` lots of those `masked_shift_left()`s together. But I don't think that is optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You could store functions in your lookup table:

```
table = [
    lambda x:x,
    lambda x:x,
    lambda x:x | ((x & 0b0001) << 1),
    ...
    ]
```

I would question why you are doing this by bit-shifting integers in Python. If it's for performance, I think doing this via a series of bit-shift operations is a bad idea. The interpreter overhead is going to utterly swamp any speed benefit that the bit-shifting could achieve. If it's for memory usage, because you need to fit millions of these in memory, you would probably do well to look at numpy, which can create memory-efficient arrays and apply operations simultaneously across the whole array.

One good reason I could think of for doing this in Python is because you want to experiment with the algorithm before implementing it in a low level language like C. Even then, I suspect the performance benefit would only be noticeable if you're working on very constrained hardware or doing some very intensive calculations - perhaps you are simulating tens of thousands of games of Bejeweled. If you are just doing this to calculate the logic for a single instance of the game played by a human in real-time, I doubt the bit-shifting optimization is going to be meaningful.

If you're intent on doing this with bit-shifting, could you perhaps do something like this? Rather than do it in a single step, loop until there are no more bits that can "fall". You should only need to loop at most as many times as you have bits in your integer.

Suppose you have this pattern:

```
        PATTERN : ab--c--d
          HOLES : 00110110
```

Find the highest set bit: the leftmost hole. (You can do something quite similar to this: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2 )

```
  LEFTMOST HOLE : 00100000
```

Now eliminate *just* that hole. Everything on the left won't change. Everything on the right will shift left by one. Create masks for these areas.

```
       CAN FALL : 00011111  ( == LEFTMOST HOLE - 1)
   WON'T CHANGE : 11000000  ( == invert CAN FALL and shift left )
```

Use those masks to chop up, shift and reassemble all your other bitfields.

```
      KEEP THIS : ab
     SHIFT THIS :    -c--d
         RESULT : ab-c--d-
```

Finally, repeat the process until the CAN FALL mask selects only holes. It won't perform your operation in the strict minimum number of operations, but it should be relatively understandable and not require the complexity of large lookup tables.

Comment: There would only be 256 entries in the lookup table. Is it *possible* to do what I want, and have that be more efficient than the method you have described? Also, for your method, I would do `pattern = (pattern & ~leftmost_hole) << 1`, right?

Comment: Well I timed each solution with `timeit` and I got some interesting results. The other solution using string manipulation: `43.593s`. Your solution: `17.549s`. Using a lookup table with non-optimal functions: `5.742s`. That's a very noticeable `7.6x` improvement from worst to best there, even with the interpreter 'utterly swamping' any speed benefits. The timing was based on evaluating every possible combination of `n` and `x` 100 times (a total of `6,553,600` calls).

Comment: I added a bit to the end of my question. Using the naive function for 8 bits: `9.714s`. If that function could be reduced to 7 operations, I'm sure it will be faster than even a lookup table with optimal functions.

Comment: I really think you need to give us more information about what this is for. We *can* try lots of crazy stuff to optimize the Python, but there's not even a full order of magnitude between your timing results. Is this a bottleneck for your program, or is this just for fun? I'm concerned you're putting in all this effort to get x5 speedups when a) it might not matter at all, and b) if it *does* matter, there are very possibly ways to get x100 speedups.

Comment: It's a bottleneck in my 'just for fun' and 'educational-ish' program. So to answer your question: both.

Comment: What are these x100 speedups you speak of?

Comment: No guarantees, but I *expect* something written in C/Java/C# could be much faster. Or if you can heavily vectorize the problem you might get a lot of benefit from numpy. This type of calculation is probably among the worst sort of thing to do in Python - lots and lots of tiny cheap operations, so the interpreter overheads account for a large proportion of your run-time. If you want it to go fast, you need to find a way to move the inner loops out of Python.

Comment: I wrote it in C++ and had around 1.5 million cascades a second. Cascades include the match removal as well as gravity though, so I'm not sure exactly how long the gravity part is taking.

Comment: Just for fun, I tried a numpy implementation, but I got a bit bored before I got to timing it: https://gist.github.com/weeble/a2a2313a7bbda6a9802c It supports a board of up to 32 rows (64 if you change it to 64-bit integers) and unlimited columns. I'd guess it might not be competitive at small board sizes, but it might be interesting at large sizes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(t, x):  # template, number to convert
    t = bin(t).replace("0b", "").rjust(8, "0")
    x = bin(x).replace("0b", "").rjust(8, "0")
    return int("".join([x[i] for i, b in enumerate(t) if int(b)]).ljust(8, "0"), 2)
```